# Chat user list is jumping a line

Tags: bug, design, chat

I looked at the user list while in the chat and noticed there were 2 lines with 1 user on each.

[image: Screenshot]

The 3rd lin contains user [@TrentHawkins](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/47157/trent-hawkins) while the 4th line only has [@hwlau](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2520/hwlau).  Additionally, the entire 4th row seems to be a link for that user while only the user-picture links the user on the 3rd line.

System info:
64-bit Windows 7 Firefox 23.0.3

Comment: Interesting.  Which browser are you using?  I have Firefox, and it's not doing this.

Comment: @Frank That could be helpful, added

Comment: This has happened to me before, I can't remember when. It doesn't seem to be affected me now though.